# Microsoft Access: Query by Form with Multiple Criteria and Possible Blanks in SQL View

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have started to create a Query by Form using the Form QueryHelp and the Query called DEALLOG3. My goal is for the user to be able to filter by Submarket, Building Type, and a sale date range. With the criteria I have now, it works fine in most scenarios where all of the comboboxes have values. However, when one of the comboboxes is blank, I want to be able to still have the other two criteria working, while showing all of the records for the blank field. (ex: Tampa Submarket, [Blank] Building Type, and a sale date from 01/01/2000 to 01/01/2016).

I've been scouring this sight for the past two days and can't find anything that will work. I think I might be looking for a dynamic query, but I am unsure. Here is what I have currently, please let me know if you can help:

```
SELECT DEALLOG3.PROPERTY, DEALLOG3.CODE, DEALLOG3.CLOSED, DEALLOG3.Submarket, DEALLOG3.NRA, DEALLOG3.PRICE, DEALLOG3.OCCUPANCY, DEALLOG3.[5 YR IRR], DEALLOG3.PURCHASER, DEALLOG3.SELLER, [PRICE]/[NRA]
    AS PSF, [DEALLOG3]![NOI]/[PRICE]
    AS [Cap Rate], DEALLOG3.[Building Type]

FROM DEALLOG3

WHERE (((DEALLOG3.CLOSED) 
    Between [Forms]![QueryHelp]![closeyear1]
    And [Forms]![QueryHelp]![closeyear2])
    AND ((DEALLOG3.Submarket)=IIf(IsNull([Forms]![QueryHelp]![Submarket]), " * " ,[Forms]![QueryHelp]![Submarket]))
    AND ((DEALLOG3.[Building Type])=IIf(IsNull([Forms]![QueryHelp]![BuildingType]),"*",[Forms]![QueryHelp]![BuildingType])))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try again after changing your WHERE clause in

```
WHERE DEALLOG3.CLOSED Between [Forms]![QueryHelp]![closeyear1] 
AND [Forms]![QueryHelp]![closeyear2]
AND (
    DEALLOG3.Submarket)=[Forms]![QueryHelp]![Submarket]) 
    OR [Forms]![QueryHelp]![Submarket] Is Null
    )
AND (
    DEALLOG3.[Building Type])=[Forms]![QueryHelp]![BuildingType] 
    OR [Forms]![QueryHelp]![BuildingType] Is Null
    )
```